# Chrome Emulator not working properly

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, emulation

Today, Google has released the latest Chrome. The emulator is not working correctly on JQM. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Yesterday, all touch events were working fine before this latest update...

Comment: Even going to the google site after an F12, the site doesn't function properly on clicks. Something definitely wrong with this latest chrome update.

Comment: Would like to know the answer to this too. Just wasted a lot of time trying to debug something that was broken by an emulator I thought I could trust.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is described here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415053

A simple workaround until the update is out, is here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415053#c21

Comment: Very helpful.. I spend a few days fiddling with my code not knowing there is a problem with GOOGLE... !!!! Thanks