# HTML5 Mobile webpage - Touch area issues

Tags: android, html, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create a mobile webpage, my page has a form which user can fill details and submit. When try using Chrome emulator found the touch/click is very inconsistent (have attached the screenshot of it).. Its hard to click inside the input box, it seems like the buttons are not clickable sometimes (when trying to click on a button it highlights some other elements as if I clicked on that), it clicks on them occasionally correct. I think there is some way to define your clickable elements area, or I don't know.. sorry I am new to mobile development.

below is extract of my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Dragend JS mobile demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      padding: 15px;
      font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #demo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      background: #457;
      cursor: hand;
      cursor: -moz-grab;
      cursor: -webkit-grab;
      cursor: grab;
    }

    #demo li.first {
      background: #577;
    }

    #demo li.middle {
      background: #1e8;
    }

    #demo li.last {
      background: #e8b;
    }

    #dragend {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      right: 50px;
      background: #345;
      padding: 18px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      width: 150px;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    #dragend h1 {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #dragend a {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #fff
    }

    #demo p {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 30px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #demo p:first-child {
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    #demo p:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 200px;
    }

  </style>


</head>
<body>

  <div id="demo">
    <ul>
      <li class="first dragend-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, excepturi, mollitia sapiente sequi adipisci fuga reiciendis qui provident aut alias iste nam at cumque inventore dignissimos quibusdam vero pariatur delectus!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, excepturi, mollitia sapiente sequi adipisci fuga reiciendis qui provident aut alias iste nam at cumque inventore dignissimos quibusdam vero pariatur delectus!</p>
      </li>
      <li class="dragend-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, excepturi, mollitia sapiente sequi adipisci fuga reiciendis qui provident aut alias iste nam at cumque inventore dignissimos quibusdam vero pariatur delectus!</p>
        <p><input type="date" name="date" value="Deadline Date" id="date" class="shortField"></p>
        <p><input type="time" name="hour" value="Deadline Time" id="time" class="shortField"></p>
        <p>
        <input class="css_btn_formbtns" type="submit" value="Submit" style="float:left" />
        <input class="css_btn_formbtns" type="button" value="Back" style="float:right"/></p>
      </li>
      <li class="middle dragend-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, nihil fugit <a href="http://google.com">cupiditate</a> aut sit temporibus sint repellat et. Neque, harum, vel aut quidem tempore odit amet qui officiis ipsa voluptatem.</p>
     </li>
      <li class="dragend-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, nihil fugit <a href="http://google.com">cupiditate</a> aut sit temporibus sint repellat et. Neque, harum, vel aut quidem tempore odit amet qui officiis ipsa voluptatem.</p>
     </li>
      <li class="last dragend-page">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, excepturi, mollitia sapiente sequi adipisci fuga reiciendis qui provident aut alias iste nam at cumque inventore dignissimos quibusdam vero pariatur delectus!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dragend.js"></script>

  <script>

    $(function() {
      new Dragend($("#demo").get(0), {
        afterInitialize: function() {
          $("#demo").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
      });
    });

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-219062-10']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Chrome emulator, tried just above code alone and still its seems very hard to click inside the text box.

Please help..

Comment: Running your HTML in my Chrome (also selected Samsung Galaxy S4) works fine when clicking using the mouse. The Chrome controls added to the widget are very small and its not the greatest user experience. You could try using CSS to make the input box bigger and therefore easier to use (e.g. input[type="date"] { font-size: 2em }).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes you are right. It function just OK (minus the lagy user expreince) with that simple 2 controls but I have a carousel and different buttons and controls on which it does not seems to work well. I have updated my code, could you check if that is OK? Thank you for your time.. You will need the js file: http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/

Comment: Hey found the problem... You know what, its bloody GOOGLE.. :) Chck out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413472/chrome-emulator-not-working-properly